# C++ - A Good Methodology When Implementing Template ListMap

Tags: c++

I'm writing a template list map(use linked-list instead of red-black tree/BST). `listmap` is defined as

```
template <typename Key, typename Value, class Less=xless<Key>>
class listmap {
private:
   Less less;
   struct node;
public:
   class iterator;
   iterator insert (const value_type&);
   iterator insertinEmpty (const value_type&);
   iterator find (const key_type&) const;
   iterator erase (iterator position);
   iterator begin() { return anchor()->next; }
   iterator end() { return anchor(); }
   bool empty() const { return   const_cast<listmap*>(this) -> begin() 
                          ==    const_cast<listmap*>(this) -> end(); }     
   ....
};
```

So we have a `node` and `iterator` here. The program should read a file which contains lines as follows,

```
key = value      //assign or insert
key =            //list all pairs with the same key
    = value      //list all pairs with the same value
    =            //list all pairs
```

I'm wondering how to implement main.cpp. Is it good to write a listmap with pairs inside

```
("assign",    fn_assign)
("listKey",   fn_listKey)
("listVal",   fn_listVal)
("listAll",   fn_listAll)
```

And then call functions in `listmap` correspondingly? Or there's a better way?